# Como acceder y manipular una class a otra

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, class

tengo dos class en C# en la que una se llama ClNave y otra ClBala que los dos son paneles. Lo que quiero saber es como puedo acceder desde el class ClBala poder usar/manipular la posición del panel de la clase ClNave, si puede ser que no sea desde el propio Form Main y que sea desde el archivo class. Basicamente quiero poder hacer esto por ejemplo pnlBala.location = pnlNave.location más o menos.

Aquí tengo el código de la clase ClNave en la que quiero acceder a las propiedades del panel pnlNave:

```
namespace SpaceInvaders.Classes
{
class ClNave
{
    FrMain fpare;
    Panel pnlNave = new Panel();
    Int32 direccionX = 25;
    Point nuevaposicion = new Point();
    
    public ClNave(FrMain formulari)
    {
        fpare = formulari;
        iniNave();
        
    }

    private void iniNave()
    {
        pnlNave.Size = new Size(150, 18);
        pnlNave.Location = new Point(0, fpare.Height - pnlNave.Height);
        pnlNave.BackColor = Color.White;
        fpare.Controls.Add(pnlNave);
    }

    public void desplazarDerecha()
    {
        nuevaposicion.X = pnlNave.Location.X + direccionX;
        nuevaposicion.Y = pnlNave.Location.Y;

        if (nuevaposicion.X <= 0){
            nuevaposicion.X = 0;
            direccionX = -direccionX;
        }
        else
        {
            if(nuevaposicion.X + pnlNave.Width >= fpare.Width)
            {
                nuevaposicion.X = fpare.Width - pnlNave.Width;
            }
        }

        pnlNave.Location = nuevaposicion;
    }

    public void desplazarIzquierda()
    {
        nuevaposicion.X = pnlNave.Location.X - direccionX;
        nuevaposicion.Y = pnlNave.Location.Y;

        if (nuevaposicion.X <= 0)
        {
            nuevaposicion.X = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (nuevaposicion.X + pnlNave.Width >= fpare.Width)
            {
                nuevaposicion.X = fpare.Width - pnlNave.Width;
            }
        }
        pnlNave.Location = nuevaposicion;
    }
}

}
```

Aquí tengo el código de la clase ClBala, aun no esta terminado:

```
namespace SpaceInvaders.Classes
{
class ClBala
{
    Panel pnlBala = new Panel();
    FrMain fpare;
    Point nuevaPosicion = new Point();

    public ClBala (FrMain formulari)
    {
        fpare = formulari;
        iniBala();
        //posicionBala();
    }

    private void iniBala()
    {
        pnlBala.Location = new Point(50,700);
        pnlBala.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        pnlBala.Size = new Size(9, 25);
        fpare.Controls.Add(pnlBala);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: agrega el codigo.

Comment: Ya esta, lo he editado poniendo todo el código que tenia

Comment: debes pasarle la referencia de una clase a la otra.. esa es tu pregunta?

Comment: si, pero tambien tiene las clases privadas

Comment: Como podria poder desde el elemento ClBola al location del panel ClNave? No se me ocurre nada y investigando no encuentro nada

Answer (score 0):

Te falta cambiarle la accesibilidad a la clases y crear propiedades publicas que puedas acceder y modificar o metodos que modifiquen estas propiedades si las dejaste privadas.
No importa como se llamen tus clases, si no les das los accesos correspondientes.
En tu clase `CINave` coloque tu variable `nuevaposicoin` como propiedad publica y tu clase tambien, para que puedas acceder desde `CIBala`.

```
public class ClNave
{
    FrMain fpare;
    Panel pnlNave = new Panel();
    Int32 direccionX = 25;
    public Point nuevaposicion {get; set;}
    
    public ClNave(FrMain formulari)
    {
        fpare = formulari;
        iniNave();
        nuevaposicion = new Point();
    }

    private void iniNave()
    {
        pnlNave.Size = new Size(150, 18);
        pnlNave.Location = new Point(0, fpare.Height - pnlNave.Height);
        pnlNave.BackColor = Color.White;
        fpare.Controls.Add(pnlNave);
    }

    public void desplazarDerecha()
    {
        nuevaposicion.X = pnlNave.Location.X + direccionX;
        nuevaposicion.Y = pnlNave.Location.Y;

        if (nuevaposicion.X <= 0){
            nuevaposicion.X = 0;
            direccionX = -direccionX;
        }
        else
        {
            if(nuevaposicion.X + pnlNave.Width >= fpare.Width)
            {
                nuevaposicion.X = fpare.Width - pnlNave.Width;
            }
        }

        pnlNave.Location = nuevaposicion;
    }

    public void desplazarIzquierda()
    {
        nuevaposicion.X = pnlNave.Location.X - direccionX;
        nuevaposicion.Y = pnlNave.Location.Y;

        if (nuevaposicion.X <= 0)
        {
            nuevaposicion.X = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (nuevaposicion.X + pnlNave.Width >= fpare.Width)
            {
                nuevaposicion.X = fpare.Width - pnlNave.Width;
            }
        }
        pnlNave.Location = nuevaposicion;
    }
}

}
Aquí tengo el código de la clase ClBala, aun no esta terminado:

namespace SpaceInvaders.Classes
{
public class ClBala
{
    Panel pnlBala = new Panel();
    FrMain fpare;
    Point nuevaPosicion = new Point();
    private CINave Nave{get;set;}

    public ClBala (FrMain formulari)
    {
        fpare = formulari;
        iniBala();
        Nave = new CINave();
        //posicionBala();
    }
    private void CambiarPropiedad()
    {
      Nave.nuevaposicion = "tus datos";
    }

    private void iniBala()
    {
        pnlBala.Location = new Point(50,700);
        pnlBala.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        pnlBala.Size = new Size(9, 25);
        fpare.Controls.Add(pnlBala);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: En caso de que quisiera hacer que en este caso pnlBala siguiera la posición del panel nave, me es útil igual ? Muchas gracias !

Comment: @Wail, si te sirve pero esto que estas trabado, quizas es una de las cosas mas basicas cuando comienzas a desarrollar, Te recomiendo una lectura https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ para que no te demores pensando estos problemas.

Comment: En todo caso da un error a la hora de crear un *nave = new Clbala();* de que no se ha dado ningún argumento.

Comment: Tenes que pasarle el parametro que creas en tu clase, o hacer un constructor por defecto. No quiero ser insistente, pero en lugar de copiar y pegar tenes que leer la doc que te pase para que entiendas que estas haciendo y cuales son las mejores formas de realizar codigo